# GCC doesn't see __VA_ARGS__ as an argument in macro

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, macros

I have next code, which throws an error

> expected ';' before '(' token

in string with directive "using".

```
#define D1(Name, ... ) \
class Name##Postfix \
{ \
    using A1 = void (*)(__VA_ARGS__); \  
};

int main()
{
    D1(test, test1);
}
```

If I change `__VA_ARGS__` to `int`, then there is no error. I'm using the GCC (`g++`) compiler, if it's necessary.

Comment: very odd - it only triggers that issue when compiled with an unknown type. It does have the feel of a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code:

1. `test1` is not a type
2. Spaces after backslash in "using A1" line (warning)
3. `using` as type alias is supported only starting with C++11

If you fix these problems, then it compiles fine (gcc 4.9.2).